# Getting error while creating express project in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, express, npm, webstorm

Today when I create a new express project in WebStorm, I get this error:

```
Create Express Project
         Error creating Node.js Express App. Failed command:
         "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" install
         Exit code: -1
```

But I could create successfully a month ago.

My npm and node version is 2.15.9 and 4.5.0

Comment: does creating express project work in cmd console, using express-generator? Seems `npm install` failed for some reason. I'd suggest creating support ticket, providing your idea.log